# Removing White Space in a Palindrome String

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to modify the code to ignore white spaces in a Palindrome String. For example, the code should mark `Do Geese See God` as Palindrome. I've been trying to use `.replace(" ", "")`, but either an error pops up or the Palindrome is returned as `False`.

```
stk = Stack()

for i in range(len(sentence)):
    stk.push(sentence[i])

    for i in range(stk.size()):
        stk.replace(" ","")

        if sentence[i] != stk.pop():
           return False;

    return True;
```

I'm trying to not use `stk.item[-1]` or `stk.item == stk.item[::-1] in Stack`, by the way.

Comment: Then define a white space in your replacement. So it should be `.replace(" ","")`.

Comment: On a side note, your test phrase is not a Palindrome. Change `Does` to `Do` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just stripping all whitespace with a **RegEx**:

```
input = "  A man a plan a canal Panama "
input = re.sub(r'\s+', '', input)
```

This would also handle the cases of leading and trailing whitespace, which you probably also want to ignore.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about using a regex but the code will take user input and then decided if it's a palindrome or not, I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a cut and paste error but you don't actually have a space in what you are replacing.

```
stk.replace(' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the code to make this work:

```
def isPalindrome(sentence):          
   sentence = sentence.replace (' '. '')
   stk = Stack()
   for i in range(len(sentence)):
      stk.push(sentence[i])
   for i in range(stk.size()):
      stk.replace(' ','')
      if sentence[i] != stk.pop():
          return False;
   return True;
```

Comment: It seems that `stk.replace(' ','')` is not necessary